# Struggling with reveal window closing in foundatoin

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, zurb-foundation

I'm using ruby on rails 4.2.2 with gem foundation-rails 6.1.2.
I've installed everything as in the docs and now trying to make simple reveal modal window, like in foundation docs [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/reveal.html)

I've imported motion-ui, but it still doesn't work. Here is the code in slim:

```
.reveal#exampleModal1 data-reveal='data-reveal'
    h1 Awesome. I Have It.
    p.lead Your couch. It is mine.
    p I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!
    button.close-button data-close="data-close" aria-label="Close modal" type="button"
        span aria-hidden="true"&times;
```

And the link itself to open the modal:

```
a.open-modal data-open="exampleModal1" Open modal
```

So the modal is opening but has strange styles for the first opening. It's too wide(inline styles are added to the modal) and close button doesn't close the modal. If I close the modal by clicking outside the modal or ESQ - it's closed. The second time I open the reveal, it has correct width of 600px(styles pane in console shows that now styles come from some css file). But close button still doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, dealing with close button was easy thanks to opened [issue](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails/issues/160) on github

As stated in the issue, still have problem with initial styling..